# Настройка непрерывного обновления процесса при отладке golang

Tags: golang

На node.js и flask видел полезную опцию : если запустить сервер в отладке на своей машине и внести изменения в исходный код, то сервер сам перезапускается. Как такое настроить в golang?

Comment: В go нет горячей пересборки при обновлении исходников. Но вы можете воспользоваться экспериментальной фичей `docker compose watch`, которая позволяет пересобрать образ/перезапустить контейнер при обновлении исходных текстов. Подробнее https://docs.docker.com/compose/file-watch/